# DB2 build xml document from query

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

In my stored procedure, I want to build a single xml document. The query below creates 100 documents. Is it possible to declare one document which has 100 elements of type elem?

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (NAME "elem",
 XMLAttributes(Identifier as "ID", Name AS "name"))
FROM 
(
SELECT a.*
FROM OBJECTS a
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [XMLAGG function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlagg). It aggregates XML snippets. One use case is to wrapt multiple XMLELEMENTs into a single document. This example is taken from the linked documentation:

```
   SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
     CONTENT XMLELEMENT(
       NAME "Department", XMLATTRIBUTES(
         E.WORKDEPT AS "name"
       ),
       XMLAGG(
         XMLELEMENT(
           NAME "emp", E.LASTNAME
         )
         ORDER BY E.LASTNAME
       )
     )
     AS CLOB(110)
   )
   AS "dept_list"
   FROM EMPLOYEE E
   WHERE E.WORKDEPT IN ('C01','E21')
   GROUP BY WORKDEPT
```

In your case, EMPLOYEE would be OBJECTS. The query structure is very similar.

Comment: Do we have something similar in json, because the query below always generates 100 CLOBS, but want to have single data
`select json_object ('id' value Identifier )
FROM OBJECTS 
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: `VALUES JSON_OBJECT ('my_arrary_name' VALUE JSON_ARRAY (SELECT Identifier FROM (VALUES 1, 2, 3) OBJECTS (Identifier) FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY))`

Comment: Your question is about XML which I answered. Please mark it answered.